# How to generate _ttrpc.pb.go file from .proto files using protoc command for ttrpc

Tags: grpc-go, ttrpc

trying to write a sample grpc using light weight ttrpc repo.

Question is not able to generate _ttrpc.pb.go files from .proto using protoc command.

can anyone help with the code generation from proto files as show in the example here https://github.com/containerd/ttrpc/blob/main/example/example_ttrpc.pb.go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first install the binary **protoc-gen-go-ttrpc** from source repo

$ cd ttrpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-ttrpc
$ go install

this will put a binary file **protoc-gen-go-ttrpc.exe** in %**GOBIN**% directory

now in example folder.
run the following protoc command with ttrpc plugin

```
 protoc -I ../pb --go_out=. --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-ttrpc_out=plugins=ttrpc:../pb  ../pb/hello.proto
```

this will generate the following files.

pb
|__ hello.proto
|__ hello.pb.go
|__ hello.ttrpc.pb.go